How can I create a dried glue substance?
I'm creating a static model of a DIY gun, and would like to add a thick
line of a dried adhesive/glue substance. It should look like it has been squeezed from a tube, or glue-gun, with a similar consistency as the glue in the image below:

What is the best way to model the shape of the glue line?
Here's a screenshot of my project, The yellow rectangle indicates where I want the glue to sit, in the gap between the wooden plank and the metal pipe:


will glue added with the DIY gun in an animation? Or is it a still image and you are just looking for a way to model the shape of the glue line?

Hi, Matt.. agreed .. it's important to know whether this is intended to be an animation.

the material seems pretty basic, a white color with a low Roughness?

@Blunder thank you, I've edited my question. I want to know the best way to model the shape of the glue line - no animation required.

I would use a cylinder or a Bézier curve converted to a mesh with enough resolution and then add a Displace modifier with a Cloud texture. The specific settings are up to you, tweaking the results until you like the look.
To get more variation you could also use two Displace modifiers, one with a larger cloud texture and one with a smaller texture. Or also add a Subdivision Surface modifier for finer details. But that is all dependent on personal preference.
Basic mesh object:

Basic modifier setup:

Possible result:


Thank you so much - this is exactly what I'm looking for.

You're welcome. You could also experiment with other textures than Cloud. This answer is just for the general idea.
